# how to re-position any element in jquery click function?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs, accordion

I would like to create a tab section like this. I can able to open tabs using toggle function, but not sure how to re-position the element on second click to close the tab. Below is the link for example, how I would like to make the tabs.. can anyone help me on it?

http://www.msia.org/experience/planting-light-columns

Comment: Would be helpful if you please provide us some code.
What do you mean by re-position?

Comment: Hello Carlos, I am using this script to open tab and float title to the left- 
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".button").click(function(){
     $(this)
        .css('float','right')
      $(".content").toggle();
     });

    
   
     
   
    });
   </script>  Now I want, to float none the title on second click to close the tab. so it will look as it is, before open the tab. Is that clear now? Let me know if not, I will try it again, -  http://www.msia.org/experience/planting-light-columns   this is the example of what I want to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeAttr to remove float and you will have it in the initial state. 
**`$(this).removeAttr('float');`**

Alternatively 
**`$(this).css("float", "none");`**

```
if ($(this).is(':visible')){
        $(this).css('float','left');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But can you help to understand, How and where  to apply removeAttr here  -    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".button").click(function(){
     $(this)
        .css('float','right')
      $(".content").toggle();
     
     });

    
   
    });
   </script>

Comment: I add an example how to check if the tab is visible or not and apply the float. Alternatively you can have different sets of css classes. 
$(this).addClass(".className");